# What are the .bat files of a Qt6 installation used for?

Tags: c++, windows, qt, cmake, qt6

When I build and install Qt6 (tested with 6.5.1) on Windows 11 with the Visual Studio 2019 MSVC compiler, I get some `.bat` files in the install directory:

```
bin/qmake.bat
bin/qt-cmake.bat
bin/qt-cmake-private.bat
bin/qt-cmake-standalone-test.bat
bin/qt-configure-module.bat
bin/qt-internal-configure-tests.bat
bin/qtpaths.bat
```

It looks like the build path is hard encoded in these files which would make the installation non-relocatable. E.g. `qtpaths.bat`:

```
@echo off
C:\Temp\tt\wd\build\qt_generated\host\bin\qtpaths.exe -qtconf "%~dp0\target_qt.conf" %*
```

What are these files used for?

Comment: qt installation is not relocatable, qmake paths are writen during make install phase